# Synchronize my asp.net application with Google calendar, outlook calendar and other main stream calendar services

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar, icalendar

I have to create an application that needs to synchronize with Google, outlook or any other popular calendar services. It need to be two way meaning updates and events from google/outlook calendar needs to be visible and editable in my application and vice versa.

I have been searching for a while in hope to find something like Email services that can be synchronized using Imap and Smtp servers.

I found out that .ics file can be used to export and import calendar data. But in my case it need to be real time synchronization from both sides.

Are there any APIs or libraries i can use? Or any other way to do it?
Any suggestion is welcome.
Thank you.

Comment: [Google Calendar API Push Notification](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push)

Comment: I am looking for more of a generic service that suits my requirement. Is there any? Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1):

The de facto way to synchronize calendars is a [CalDAV server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CalDAV), which reads and writes events to a local database and exposes the event details through the ICS format, wrapped in CalDAV messages.

Various clients have differing levels of support for the protocol and its extensions.

Apple iCalelndar, Mozilla Thunderbird with Lightning and Microsoft Outlook with some proprietary plugin can talk CalDAV, but each have their specific annoyances. iCalendar will refuse to remove conflicts, Lightning will get stuck with authentication issues and stop updating and the Outlook plugins, well ... suck.

One Outlook plugin in particular was designed by a developer (literally 20 tabs in the settings screen), didn't implement base64 properly (we had to pad its messages at the server) and refused to do anything useful when a debugger was active on the machine it ran on.

But that was the state of things like five years ago, and I haven't touched the subject since. I think we settled on using a Google Calendar and provide a one-way sync through ICS files.