# Synchronizable Calendar service architecture

Tags: calendar, scheduling, icalendar, caldav

Currently I'm working on creation of calendar service on java. DB schema and basic functionality is ready, and we moved to synchronization topic. The goal is to synch our calendar events to the external calendar (like Google Calendar, Apple Calendar, Open Exchange Calendar, Outlook calendar etc.)

After research I found some useful links that helped me to understand this topic a bit better.

[google calendar doesn't support CalDev synch](https://support.google.com/calendar/thread/97494333/syncing-caldav-calendar-to-google-from-caldav-to-google?hl=en)

[Almost same topic](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/369001/implementing-caldav-server-vs-sending-icals-around)

[One more topic that has no proper answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45543964/synchronize-my-asp-net-application-with-google-calendar-outlook-calendar-and-ot)

Now I don't understand why such big company as google didn't implement CalDev client. Looks like there is smth critical with it.

The main question is: what the architecture of the system should be, so it can be integrated with most usable calendars (all mentioned before) (both read these calendars and provide them information so I can see all internal events in external calendar)

For now I'm reading all information about this topic, but can't find any structured knowledges

UPD 21.07.2023: Found useful [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37886302/2-way-syncing-with-google-calendar-outlook?rq=2) where user explained how to implement synch logic without calDev stuff. He took integration with Google Calendar as a base